# MySql - Запрос на обновление

Tags: mysql, sql

Я получаю данные с бекенда которые я хочу обновить в таблице бд. Как мне сделать выборочное обновление данных без го**окода? Например, есть таблица с конструкцией `name` `title` `age`. И допустим прилетает запрос на обновление колонки `age`. Возможно ли это красиво реализовать без лишнего кода?

Comment: Да, такое возможно. Если Вы не желаете использовать go - код, можете написать PHP код и даже SQL

Comment: Можно ли привести пример? Для NodeJS, если есть такая возможность, тоже